# Excel hyperlink with a pound

Tags: angularjs, excel, hyperlink, apache-poi, ms-office

How to make a hyperlink in excel, which opens an angularjs web page (that contains a pound)?

...according to ms-office documents, we cannot use a pound character in hyperlinks:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/202261/you-cannot-use-a-pound-character-in-a-file-name-for-a-hyperlink-in-an-office-program

when I am trying to create such a link, it does not work when default browser is chrome (but work when default browser is iexplorer).

(in chrome the '#' in the link **host:port/#/books/1234** changes to: **host:port/%20-%20/books/1234**

```
String address = "localhost:8080/#/books/1234";
String title = "a book";
CellStyle hlinkstyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
Font hlinkfont = workbook.createFont(); 
hlinkfont.setUnderline(XSSFFont.U_SINGLE); 
hlinkfont.setColor(HSSFColor.BLUE.index); 
hlinkstyle.setFont(hlinkfont); 
XSSFHyperlink link = (XSSFHyperlink) createHelper.createHyperlink(Hyperlink.LINK_URL); 
link.setAddress(address); 
cell.setHyperlink(link); 
cell.setCellStyle(hlinkstyle); 
cell.setCellValue(title);
```

Comment: can you show your link

Comment: updated in the original question

Comment: I'm using apache-poi version 3.15 and the latest version of chrome browser and I don't have a problem with pound symbol in the hyperlinks.
Can you add some code to the question?

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `http://` in front of `localhost:8080/#/books/1234`.

This code does not use apache-poi, but it works to create a hyperlink in Excel. It does **not** work if I don't use `http://` in front of the address.

```
string fileName = @"C:/Users/eric.sundquist/Desktop/book2.xlsx";
string address = "http://localhost:8889/#/sign-in";
string title = "a book";

Application excel = new Application();
Workbook file = excel.Workbooks.Open(fileName);

Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)file.Worksheets[1];
Range range = sheet.get_Range("A1", "A1");

range[1, 1].Hyperlinks.Add(range, address, Type.Missing, address, title);
file.Save();
file.Close();
```

Comment: I added http:// but still not working. See again the ms-office documents link I attached above. to reproduce this make sure your default browser is iexplorer.

Comment: I wonder if it is an issue with the POI library, then. I changed me default browser to IE, reran this code, and still didn't have any problems with it. My code is just using the C# Interop.Excel library. It doesn't seem to replace the `#` in the link. It must be your the `XSSFHyperlink` or your `createHelper` which is changing the `#` to ` - `.